# Increasing font weight (making it bolder) in Firefox on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, fonts

My laptop screen got burned so I use an external monitor, but all fonts look very thin for some reason.

How can I bolden-up fonts in Firefox?

---

P.S.

- I didn't find any info that helps, most tricks relate either to changing color or zooming, but i don't want to zoom, I want to thicken things up.
- Also I know, Firefox options allow to choose font types and sizes, but not weight or boldness, so this doesn't help either.
- Messing with my monitor's menu does thicken fonts, but they appear blurred so this is not a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Too bad you are on windows XP. Windows 7 and up have the Clear Font wizard which allows you to make all fonts thicker.

Comment: yes. need some XP workaround